# How to import excel file into two tables with input tags at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have two table one is users and the next one is students, the students table store the data of users based on their role. and the relation between user and student is user_id in students table.
And the form includes three inputs for text and one for excel file to import. I want to import the users by file and their data by inputs.
my form is like this:

```
<form method='post' action="{{ route('importExcel') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
          <div class="box-body row">
                        
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="faculty" class="col-md-12">فاکولته</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name='faculty' class="form-control" id="faculty">
                            <option value=""> انتخاب فاکولته </option>
                        @foreach($faculties as $faculty)
                            <option value="{{ $faculty->id }}" >{{ $faculty->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="department" class="col-md-12">دیپارتمنت</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="department" id="department"> 
                        <option value="">انتخاب دیپارتمنت</option>
                        @foreach($departments as $department)
                            <option value="{{ $department->id }}">{{ $department->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="sesson" class="col-md-12">فصل</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="sesson" id="sesson" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">انتخاب فصل</option>
                        <option value="spring">بهار</option>
                        <option value="fall">خزان</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="file" class="col-md-12">فایل اکسل</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="file">
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <input type="hidden" name="role" value="user">
            <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="admin">
            
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left submit">تایید</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </form>
```

and my import class is like this:

```
class UsersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            User::create([
                'name'     => str_replace(' ', '_', $row['name']), 
                'email'    => $row['email'], 
                'password' => bcrypt(str_replace(' ', '_', $row['name'])),
                'role'     => 'user',
            ]);

            Student::create([
                'user_id' =>  DB::table('users')->getPdo()->lastInsertId(),
                'department_id' => $row['department'],
                'faculty_id'    => $row['faculty'],
                'sesson'        => $row['sesson']
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

and my controller is like this:

```
try{
            $this->validate($request,[
                'faculty' => 'required',
                'department'=> 'required',           
                'sesson'=> 'required',           
                'file'=> 'required',           
            ]);

            $file = $request->file('file');
            $faculty =  $request-> faculty;
            $department = $request -> department;
            $sesson = $request -> sesson;

           Excel::import(new UsersImport,[$file, $faculty, $department, $sesson]);
           return redirect()->route('admin.students')->with('success','عملیات موفقانه انجام شد.');
            
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error','عملیات انجام نشد!');
        }
```

but its not working, the error is like this: **pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

Comment: The error is right - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php. but where is the call to path info in the code you've shown? If you're going to tell us about an error it would make sense to show the code where it occurs

Comment: There is no function to call path info, I do know why there is error like that.

Comment: The full error message should contain a stack trace showing you exactly which line it occurs on, in which file, and all the functions which are called in between.